# Why trailing comma in if-else expression's second condition causes first condition to be casted to tuple

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, tuples

The syntax of declaring tuples with commas is clear and everywhere I saw it it is being used with literals enclosed in braces e.g. `(1,)`.

However, python does allow to use commas without enclosing braces to declare tuples, and there is strange behavior in one particular case, see the code below.

```
def ifElseExpressionTrailingComma():
    return 1 if True else 0,

def ifElseExpressionTrailingCommaWrapped():
    return 1 if True else (0,)

print ifElseExpressionTrailingComma()
print ifElseExpressionTrailingCommaWrapped()
```

Output:

```
(1,) # what??
1
```

Tested on 2.7 and 3.5.
Can someone explain why 1 is implicitly converted to the tuple?

Comment: It's not implicit. The ternary expression is resolved to a single value, either one or zero, *then* the trailing comma makes it a tuple. In the second case the parentheses mean that one possible return value from the expression is a tuple, the other is an integer. Given the code you've written demonstrates this behaviour clearly it's not obvious what kind of answer you're expecting.

Comment: yes, that was not very obvious that comma is applied to the evaluated result of the ternary because it has lower priority. Thanks, guys.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The code does indeed show this, but to complete my answer, was trying to find this precedence documented, but couldn't https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: @Chris_Rands the comma isn't an operator: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-s-up-with-the-comma-operator-s-precedence

Comment: @jonrsharpe Of course, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply the order of operations:

```
>>> 1 if True else 0,
(1,)
>>> (1 if True else 0),
(1,)
>>> 1 if True else (0,)
1
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because the ternary operator (`a if b else c`) is stronger than the "comma" operator.

You may compare it with logical `or` and `and` operators where `and` is stronger than `or`:

```
if foo and bar or bats:

# means:
if (foo and bar) or bats:
```